# Extract only package name without version using awk or sed

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, awk

```
cat pkg.temp
ca-certificates-2017.2.14-65.0.1.el6_9.noarch
glusterfs-3.7.9-12.el6.x86_64
glusterfs-api-3.7.9-12.el6.x86_64
glusterfs-api-devel-3.7.9-12.el6.x86_64
glusterfs-client-xlators-3.7.9-12.el6.x86_64
```

Here is a file , I want the output as :

```
PkgName                        Version
ca-certificates                2017.2.14-65.0.1.el6_9.noarch
glusterfs                      3.7.9-12.el6.x86_64
glusterfs-api-devel            3.7.9-12.el6.x86_64
glusterfs-client-xlators       3.7.9-12.el6.x86_64
```

This way I get unwanted hyphen at the last:

```
$ awk -F'[[:digit:]]' '{ print $1}'
ca-certificates-
glusterfs-
glusterfs-api-
glusterfs-api-devel-
glusterfs-client-xlators-
```

While printing $2 wont display my version either

```
awk -F'[[:digit:]]' '{ print $2}' /tmp/Version-pkgs

.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are confident that the delimiter combination is "-" followed by a digit, you can use sed to replace that dash with a space.  You can the pipe this through awk to do some formatted printing.  Something like this:

```
sed -e 's/-\([0-9]\)/ \1/' _file_ | awk 'BEGIN {printf("%-30s %s\n", "PkgName", "Version")} {printf("%-30s %s\n", $1, $2)}'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 although personally I'd replace the awk fixed-width formatting with a `column -t`